# CMD and Powershell (SQL) commands remote computer

Tags: sql-server, powershell, cmd

I am writing script with choices and some of commands are command prompt, CMD SQL and powershell.

```
POWERSHELL: Invoke-command -computername $computer -scriptblock{Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "select * from lastreceipt" | where {$_.CreationTime.date -eq '%2017-06-21%'}}
```

ERROR: Invalid object name 'lastreceipt'.

```
C:\>sql -p base1//password "select * from lastreceipt where creationtime like '%2017-06-21%' and LOGSTACKID = 'RLOG_WED'"

LEVEL = 00

LOGSTACKID = RLOG_WED

PROGRAMID = SALESSTA

CREATIONTIME = 2017-06-21 00:00:10

TERMINALNUMBER = 2

RECEIPTNUMBER = 3232

RECEIPTTIME = 2017-06-21 21:07:45

OFFSET = 4386

LOGSTATUS = READY

LASTUPDATETIME = 2017-06-21 21:09:00
```

Works just fine but with powershell can't get it work.
I have over 1000 servers where I need that to work.

Comment: Sql –p base1//password "select * from salesendingcontrol where STARTDATE='VVVV-KK-PP'"

Comment: that one to. I am searched everywhere but can find answer to my problem

Comment: In your CMD command, is  "SQL" the same as "SQLCMD.EXE"?

Comment: See what is actually coming out. `Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock { Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "select * from lastreceipt" | Get-Member`

Comment: Or maybe just:
Invoke-command -computername $computer -scriptblock{Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "select * from lastreceipt where creationtime like '%2017-06-21%' and LOGSTACKID = 'RLOG_WED'"}

Comment: I don't know that powershell command very well, but is there a possibility that you'd need to specify user/password as you did with your `sql` command?

Answer (score -1):

> ERROR: Invalid object name 'lastreceipt'.

It tells you in the error.. Your query is incorrect.